# Deny user permissions to reg value?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, registry, user-permissions

I'm trying to make a basic trial period method to my application adding a invisible reg key and also denying the user to delete that value but I don't know how to deny user permission like "SetACL.exe" tool does.

This is my code:

```
    Dim _0day As String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0")) ' MA==


        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApplication", _
                                      "¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?", _
                                      _0day, _
                                      Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)

    ' Next step:
    ' Deny user acces (Delete/Modify) to that value (not to the entire key).
```

> Update:

Tried this but it does nothing, it runs without errors but don't deny the permissions.

```
Dim f As New RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.NoAccess, "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApplication")
f.Deny()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as suggestion, instead of creating a key to denote your app installation on the user's machine as trial, why not make the presence of a key with a valid encrypted value to identify the app as licensed? In that way, if the user removed or modified the key, your app will run in trial mode.

And make sure the encrypted key value is unique to the user's machine, so that when the key is copied to another machine, it will not work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but you can extend this comment?:"why not make the presence of a key with a valid encrypted value to identify the app as licensed?", I can understand english but I don't understanded much that even using googletranslate, are you sure with your suggestion I can measure the days elapsed for a trial period? your suggestion seems to make a unique key (MD5 based on hardware ID for example) and don't change the value, but then how I measure the days elapsed?

Comment: Sorry. I guess I missed that part about trial period. I thought your app are either running in full, or trial mode with limited features. Anyway, what you can do is during installation, create the encrypted key value containing the unique machine/hardware id, along with the installation date. In case the key is missing or modified, your app should able to detect and act accordingly (like refuse to run or something like that).

Comment: The bad thing is my application is distributed as standalone portable, but thanks for that idea for installers.

Answer (score 1):

Make the registry value the date the trial started, combined with the hardware Id, and encrypted.

Make the licensed value past date (like 1/1/1900).